# How to remove excess white space in this Image with Text Parallax CSS

Tags: css, margin, parallax

I want to know how can I remove the white spacing below, and on the edges? I already tried to remove the margin tag in the CSS code but it still didn't fix the problem. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

```js
(function($) {
  /** change value here to adjust parallax level */
  var parallax = -0.8;

  var $bg_images = $(".wp-block-cover-image");
  var offset_tops = [];
  $bg_images.each(function(i, el) {
    offset_tops.push($(el).offset().top);
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var dy = $(this).scrollTop();
    $bg_images.each(function(i, el) {
      var ot = offset_tops[i];
      $(el).css("background-position", "50% " + (dy - ot) * parallax + "px");
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.wp-block-cover-image {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  min-height: 630px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wp-block-cover-image .wp-block-cover-image-text,
.wp-block-cover-image h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.25;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 670px;
  padding: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wp-block-cover-image.has-background-dim:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.wp-block-cover-image {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wp-block-cover-image has-background-dim" style="background- 
    image:url(https://static.wixstatic.com/media/cada49_c9adefa3849b4205bb675e04076fec28~mv2.jpg)">
  <p class="wp-block-cover-image-text"><strong>
    ABOUT US<br><br>    
    WHO WE ARE<br><br>
    Cakes by Sophie specializes in bespoke cakes and pastries for all types of events.  The finest 
    ingredients and utmost care go into each of our products. This is why Cakes by Sophie speak love.  
    When you want nothing but the best to remember life's greatest events, Cakes by Sophie is here for 
    you. <br><br>
    OUR MISSION<br><br>
    To bring you joy with every bite of our products, and to be a part of your best memories.<br>
    </strong></p>
</div>
```

I need to know what is wrong with this code, I cant remove the white spacing below. Thanks in advance!

[See Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv6dr.jpg)

Comment: I can see neither an image nor whitespace around it when I run your code.

Comment: I tried to copy the codes and run in notepad as saved as .html, and still it shows the excess whitepace below, it doesnt show the full image

Comment: I added an image of what it looks like when view directly on .html file via notepad

Comment: I also try to add   height: 100%;   on the <div class> and html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       but still it didnt fixed the excess white space below.

Comment: Could you check your snippet and make sure it shows your problem - as @connexo has pointed out the snippet currently does not show any image.